# Keyed Particle Simulation acting weird

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

i have two particle system, one follows a curve with normal physics,
other one is keyed, used to form a gem from the particles.

the problem is the simulation works fine in viewport but in render the particles of the gem spawns from a random place

any help?

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you baked the simulation?

Comment: yep, the keyed ones dont get baked tho, it doesnt have the cache option, i did a "bake all dynamics"